# calculate the variance and expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, variance

So we have $50$ white balls. We draw balls one after another with returning and if it is white ball we repaint it into red one. Let $X$ be the number of red balls after $20$ drawing. Calculate $\mathbb{E}X$ and $VarX$

I thought to define new random variable such that: $X_i=1$ when $i$-th drawing ball is white and $X_i=0$ when it isn't white. And now we have $X=\sum_{i=1}^{20}X_i$. But I'm afraid that it isn't a good idea because it's very hard to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)$

Do you know how to calculate it properly?

Comment: What you said about $P(X_1X_2=1)$ in a comment on my answer was *not* correct (I misinformed you in a comment). Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the *balls* numbers $1,2,\dots,50$ and let $X_i$ take value $1$ if ball $i$ is painted red after $20$ drawings and let it take value $0$ if not.

Then $X=X_1+\cdots+X_{50}$.

By linearity of expectation and symmetry we find:$$\mathbb EX=50\mathbb EX_1$$ and $$\text{Var}X=\sum_{i=1}^{50}\sum_{j=1}^{50}\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=50\text{Var}X_1+50(50-1)\text{Covar}(X_1,X_2)$$

It remains to find $\mathbb EX_1$, $\text{Var}X_1$ and $\text{Covar}(X_1,X_2)$.

---

**edit** (I informed you wrong in my comment and this is to repair that):

$$P\left(X_{1}X_{2}=1\right)=$$$$1-P\left(X_{1}=0\vee X_{2}=0\right)=1-P\left(X_{1}=0\right)-P\left(X_{2}=0\right)+P\left(X_{1}=0\wedge X_{2}=0\right)$$

This with $$P\left(X_{1}=0\wedge X_{2}=0\right)=\left(\frac{48}{50}\right)^{20}$$

Comment: Im sorry, but I still have problem. It became more clear to me but still. SO I have $EX_1=P(X_1=1)=P($first ball would be drawn$)$ and I don't know how much is it. At the begginig I thought that it was $\frac{1}{50}$

Comment: Is it just $EX_1=\frac{20}{50}$?

Comment: No. It equals the probability that ball $1$ is painted red after $20$ draws wich is $1-\left(\frac{49}{50}\right)^{20}$. Note that ball $1$ is *not* painted red if $20$ times another ball was drawn. For each time we have probability $\frac{49}{50}$ that this occurs.

Comment: Ooo thanks now I see it!!

Comment: $VarX_1=EX_1^2-(EX_1)^2=EX_1-(EX_1)^2$ and $Cov(X_1,X_2)=EX_1X_2-EX_1EX_2$ random variable $X_1X_2$ has $0-1$ distribution: $P(X_1X_2=1)=1-\frac{48}{50}^20$ and $Cov(X_1,X_2)=EX_1X_2-EX_1EX_2$ random variable $X_1X_2$ has $0-1$ distribution: $P(X_1X_2=1)=1-(\frac{48}{50})^{20}$